# Train/Test-Split: Set seed with "random_state" accross different notebooks

Tags: python, machine-learning, train-test-split

i've already worked with the "train_test_split"-Module from Sklearn. To compare the performance of different models it makes sense to set a seed with random_state, to make sure that the split is every time the same.
As i am trying out several different models in different Jupyter Notebooks I wanted to ask what is the best way to to get everytime the same Train/Test split?

In my mind there are two options:

OPTION 1: Do it like this with random_state:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data["translated_texts"], data["claim"], 
                                   stratify = data["claim"],test_size=0.10, random_state=1)
```

But I am not sure if the split is the same if I use the same random state number in a different notebook.

OPTION 2:

- create local csv-Files (Train.csv, Test.csv) to make sure the split doesn't change. But how can I then make sure to split the Data equally to specific labels. Here is a example:

  ```
   rows = []
   for i in range(50):
    rows.append(["en", i + 1])
    rows.append(["hi", i + 1])
    rows.append(["ta", i + 1])
    rows.append(["ml", i + 1])

   df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Language", "Text"])
   print(df)
  ```

How do I now split the data to get the same amount of texts from a specific language? (There are 5 differnt languages with 1000 entries in the dataset and I want for example 0.25% for every language in the test data)

Thanks for your answers!
Kind regards

Comment: Both options should work. For splitting the data according to languages, can you post a minimal reproducible snippet? Or at least make the dataframe copy-pastable instead of image.

Comment: I've edited the post with a sample dataset!